# TexMaker no longer compiles after upgrade to OS 10.12 (Sierra)

Tags: texmaker, mactex, mac

For years I have been using TexMaker on my mac with the previous OS (11). I was prompted to upgrade and after doing so, TexMaker would no longer compile my documents. I have updated my TexMaker and MacTex to the most recent versions and suspect that I need to update some of the file paths in my TexMaker preferences, but I read that newer versions of TexShop should be robust to old file path specifications. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Texmaker or TeXShop?  And just to be sure: what reply do you get if you issue the command `echo $PATH` on a Terminal shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it really years you worked under OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) or were you using a previous OS version? I ask because if it really was under OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) or earlier you may indeed need to update some preferences in TeXmaker (although I'd guess it should self-configure unless you manually changed something before). Please read the information at <http://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html> and, especially the `Updating For El Capitan' document linked there.

Comment: Hi Herb, thanks for your help. From the link you sent, I followed the directions from <http://www.tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf> section 7.4, replacing all the "usr/texbin/" segments with "/Library/Tex/texbin". It seems to be working now.